# Como selecionar um texto de link de imagem (html) e apagar todo o resto com Regex?

Tags: html, regex, google, link

Estou trabalhando com um arquivo CSV (tipo XML), estou utilizando uma planilha do google para poder dar uma limpada no dados, gostaria de editar um conjunto de celulas fazendo uma seleção de um link de imagem em html e apagar todo o restante da celula utilizando Regex.

A planilha do google tem o recurso de interpretar expressões regulares(regex) na localização e substituição de um item.

Um exemplo do link de imagem é o seguinte:

```
src="https://exemplo.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/30656289_1739197086123960_7879125475971301376_o.jpg"
```

Gostaria de localizar sempre o `src="https://exemplo.files.wordpress.com/`

Em seguida selecionar o restante da frase até o fechamento das aspas. 
Neste exemplo seria:

```
/2018/04/30656289_1739197086123960_7879125475971301376_o.jpg
```

Por fim apagar todo o conteúdo da celular e manter somente esta parte do texto:

```
/2018/04/30656289_1739197086123960_7879125475971301376_o.jpg
```

Algum sábio consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Não tem como testar agora, mas tente `src\="https:\/\/exemplo.files.wordpress.com(.*?)"`

Answer (score 2):

Use a expressão:

```
src\="https:\/\/exemplo\.files\.wordpress\.com(.*?)"
```

no campo substituir coloque `$1` que é equivalente ao grupo 1: `(.*?)`

Podes testar a expressão em [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rNZeRF/2)

Comment: Os `.` sem ser o do grupo, não seriam `\.` ?

Comment: Verdade, tinha esquecido.